# IOS react native onSelectionChange moves cursor to initial position when multline set to true

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a basic text input with multiline set to true. Additionally it has `selection` and `onSelectionChange` props set which causes cursor to move to initial position whenever there is change in `onChangeText`.

Here it's the video : https://streamable.com/bchsz4

Here it's the repro : https://github.com/VivekNeel/IOS_SELECTION_CHANGE
Here it's the sample code :

```
  <TextInput
      onChangeText={handleChange}
      value={value}
      multiline
      selection={selection}
      onSelectionChange={handleSelection}
      placeholder="Enter a text"
      style={{marginTop: 100, marginHorizontal: 16}}
    />
```

Comment: remove onSelectionChange prop from TexInput

Comment: When you have selection prop, you must have onSelectionChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just not using `selection` props fixes this!